# I can't access to My web site Symfony [ You are not allowed to access this file ]

Tags: php, symfony, host

I hosted my website; a Symfony2 application, whene I try to Access to my website 
this message is show.

```
You are not allowed to access this file. Check app_dev.php for more information
```

The link is :

```
http://something.com/web/app_dev.php/
```

When I try to access in production mode, this is the message :

```
Fatal error: Class 'AppBundle\AppBundle' not found in /htdocs/app/AppKernel.php on line 19
```

I don't have this folder `htdocs` in `/` of my hosting

Comment: You should create another question for your second problem. It is not convenient for next people who will face your problem.

Comment: I answered how to solve your first problem. But I will discuss and answer you your second problem only after you will place it in another question.

Answer (score 27):

You faced the problem of authorization to dev-environment.

If you open `app_dev.php` you will see next code:

```
// This check prevents access to debug front controllers that are deployed by accident to production servers.
// Feel free to remove this, extend it, or make something more sophisticated.
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1')) || php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server')
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}
```

It acts as defender from other man to get access to your dev-env.

You can add your IP to the trusted IPs list and all will work fine. Trusted IPs defined in array in the code:

```
array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1')
```

Comment: Sorry for the Symfony newbie question: how do you go out to the public?

Comment: @3000, to go out to the public you need to use `app.php` front-controller that already configured to work in `prod` environment

Comment: If you put your IP and it still doesn't work it can be due to browser cache. For get it work close your browser and open it again.